# Python multiprocessing installation: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, multiprocessing

Trying to install:

```
     pip install multiprocessing
```

Getting an error:

```
Collecting multiprocessing
Using cached multiprocessing-2.6.2.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/7s/sswmssj51p73hky4mkqs4_zc0000gn/T/pip-build-8c0dk6ai/multiprocessing/setup.py", line 94
    print 'Macros:'
                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/7s/sswmssj51p73hky4mkqs4_zc0000gn/T/pip-build-8c0dk6ai/multiprocessing/
```

Anyone knows the way to fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Apparently the problem is that the [multiprocessing package is only available for python 2.x](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing/2.6.2.1). I think the only solution is to download the source and fix it

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**In short: Multiprocessing is already pre-installed in python 3, no need to install it.**

I found an answer to my question and it's a silly one - multiprocessing is already pre-installed in my version of Python (3.5.2) by default.

It won't show up in the list of packages in Anaconda >> Environments >> root, as it's not a third party package but an internal one.

If anyone is not sure whether this applies to you, just check `from multiprocessing import Pool` in your Python console.

This is true of all currently supported versions of Python (2.7 and 3.x) and according to a Python maintainer/contributor `multiprocessing` has been part of the standard library (batteries included) since Python 2.6. https://bugs.python.org/msg326646

You won't need to do a `pip install multiprocessing` anymore and do NOT include it in your `requirements.txt` unless you are maintaining a Python 2.4/2.5 application (please migrate!). On most versions you can just `import multiprocessing` and you should be fine.

Comment: This is also true for Python 3.7.1

Comment: You may want to unmark the current "accepted" answer and mark this one since the other is incorrect and even using pip3 doesn't work correctly.

Comment: "multiprocessing is already pre-installed in python 3, no need to install it"  can you make this bold and first line in the answer.

Comment: How do I get the current version of multiprocessing running with my python, then?

Answer (score 14):

Instead of `pip install multiprocessing` type instead:

```
pip install multiprocess
```

Comment: Sorry it was an error in my typing. It's actually "pip" not "Pip".

Comment: The older version of the module was "multiprocessing "  for python 3 the name was changed to "multiprocess".The "multiprocessing" module was written in python 2 so when you try to install it with python 3 an error pops up.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54565506/edit) that into your answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are trying to install multiprocessing library on python3 while this library is installed on python3 by default and doesn't need to install again.
Be Lucky

Answer (score -1):

pip3.5 install multiprocessing-utils

https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing-utils/

Answer (score -1):

`python -m pip install multiprocessing`

Use python2.7 to install multiprocessing instead of using python3.5+

Answer (score -2):

Python 2.7 to 3 changed from `print "Hello World"` to `print('Hello World')` making print a function now.  Judging from the error message, it looks like `pip` or `multiprocessing` is expecting python 3.

You can check your Python version using this command:

```
python --version
```

You update pip if you already have python 3 on linux:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

For mac, you can use the equivalent homebrew command.  This should allow you to use a:

```
pip3 install multiprocessing
```

Comment: Unfortunately my python version doesn't look like 2.7. It is `Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)`.

Comment: I still get this error when running `pip3 install multiprocessing`.  Seems like pip3 is somehow still grabbing a python2 version of the module.

Comment: same here. python3 -m pip install multiprocessing return the same error SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: @p.deman I've had issues before with similar instructions as my answer when my local dev environment becomes untenable (generally due to bad PATHs or Python installed in the wrong directory).  To make my life easier, I've began using a Docker image for Python and then running the container on my machine, sort of a fresh environment for each project. I really like this one: tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask.  Another good option that i've seen a lot of folks use is `virtualenv`.

Comment: According to a Python maintainer/contributor `multiprocessing` has been part of the standard library (batteries included) since Python 2.6. You don't need to do any `pip install multiprocessing` anymore, just `import multiprocessing` and you are fine. https://bugs.python.org/msg326646

Comment: this does not solve the issue. The multiprocessing `setup.py` has python 2 code. The solution by Massyanya explains it. You don't need to install it.