# subprocess exited with error, can't install/import multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I must run a script, which calls a module, which imports `multiprocessing`.

Upon running `python script.py` in the `cmd` console, I get this error message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ctREFPROP in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (0.10.2)
Collecting multiprocessing
  Using cached multiprocessing-2.6.2.1.tar.gz (108 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\USERS\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jphwqg0y\multiprocessing_f781b3a445624f29bdb62e28b55af729\setup.py", line 94
          print 'Macros:'
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

This is identical to when I run `pip install multiprocessing`.

I noticed that `multiprocessing` ships with python natively, so I can find a folder named `multiprocessing` in `Python310\Lib`. However, it is not in the `site-packages` folder, where (if I understood correctly) `pip` installs its packages.

This is why `pip uninstall multiprocessing` yields "`WARNING: Skipping multiprocessing as it is not installed.`"

Interestingly, the problem seems to **not** occur when running the script with the python interpreter from VScode. I use python 3.10.0 from a fresh install. I upgraded `pip`, `setuptools` and `wheel` with `pip install --upgrade packagename` to no avail.

Also interestingly, running `import multiprocessing` after `python` in the `cmd` console does **not** yield the error. Any ideas?

Comment: You're using Python 2.x code with Python 3. Note that `multiprocessing` is built into modern Python releases, and doesn't need to be installed with `pip` at all in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42653828/18125313

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am aware of that, but why is it throwing the error then? The module that is imported in the script only contains a "import multiprocessing" line. Why would that try to do some python2 stuff?

Comment: So your question is "Why does my script unintentionally try to install libraries?". Then you should provide the contents of your script and how you call it. The outputs of `python --version` and `python -m pip list` commands may also be useful.

Comment: @ken Problem is actually solved now. The badly programmed module ran something like "pip install package1 package2 ..." in case some import commands would throw an error. This must be recoded into single commands. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

in the module they did `print 'Macos'` they needed to do `print("Macos")` go to `"C:\USERS\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jphwqg0y\multiprocessing_f781b3a445624f29bdb62e28b55af729\setup.py"` and on like 94 fix the error

Comment: It's futile to change code in a temporary directory, the next time the code will be downloaded the same error will happen again.

Comment: This is true, but it only happens because the OP is trying to install a python-2 release of multiprocessing instead of using the copy that's built into Python 3.

Comment: This does not work. These directories are being created on-the-fly. I found an old one, fixed the line (isn't this python 2 syntax?) but it did not change the outcome (presumably because the directory is not used anymore, instead, a new one is created). It's "temp" afterall.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's what I am assuming as well. However, how can I direct python to import the built-in module?